# How to attach new policies in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to add 3 new policies to my IAM user
[image]

I have problems here
[image]

No results,can not detect User Name.

Comment: If you go to IAM what IAM users are there?

Comment: @J.Meijers One user,that is me.

Comment: @J.Meijers There are 6 attached policies,but I want more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a role with all the policies you want attached, and attaching that role to the user. 
Attaching policies directly to a user is not really a best practice

> An IAM role is similar to a user, in that it is an AWS identity with
>   permission policies that determine what the identity can and cannot do
>   in AWS. However, instead of being uniquely associated with one person,
>   a role is intended to be assumable by anyone who needs it. Also, a
>   role does not have standard long-term credentials (password or access
>   keys) associated with it. Instead, if a user assumes a role, temporary
>   security credentials are created dynamically and provided to the user.

More can be found [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

Comment: Role name should be same as User Name?

Comment: No, you can give the role a descriptive name that descibes the superset of permissions you added, after which you can attach the role to your user. 
 
1 role can be attached to multiple users